# Windows 95 snap

Tags: 18.04, windows, snap, ubuntu-mate

I am trying to determine uses for this.

https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/windows95-snap/7059

For example I used mspaint and saved a file.

But I can not access the saved .bmp outside of the program.

Comment: I do not thing that there really are any practical uses to running windows 95 in 2018 (or later) excluding nostalgia and maybe educational purposes.

Comment: I agree with you. The windows93.net site was cute. The Wolfenstein clone brought back memories. :-)